# Is empty set a subset of a NonEmpty set?

Tags: scala

Let's imagine a function `bigset.containSubset(smallset)` which returns true/false

How should the result be for the following edge cases:

- both `bigset` and `smallset` are empty
- `bigset` is nonEmpty and `smallset` is empty

If I define arbitrarily "if the intersection of both sets gives a result identical than the smaller set, then `smallset` is a subset". Then the answer is `true` for both cases above. Is this a correct assumption?

```
scala> Set().intersect(Set())
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing] = Set()

scala> Set(1,2,3).intersect(Set())
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set()
```

Comment: This is more of a maths question than scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I learned it, the empty set is a subset of all sets. So if both sets are empty than they are the same set. If bigset is nonEmpty and smallset is empty, then smallset is a subset of bigset.

Comment: A big +1 from me. Set theory is **THE** foundation of modern mathematics. Every possible question you can think of has already been thought through and answered. Relax, turn off your brain, and let those mathematicians do your work for you! For example, some of the things mathematicians have already figured out: the empty set is a subset of all sets, including itself. Any set is a subset of itself, including the empty set. No set is a proper subset of itself, including the empty set. However, the empty set is a proper subset of all sets except itself. The union of any set with the empty set …

Comment: … is the set (IOW: the set union operation with the empty set as a neutral element form an abelian monoid). The intersection of any set with the empty set is the empty set.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Can you please elaborate a little more? "No set is a proper subset of itself, including the empty set" seems to contradict "Any set is a subset of itself, including the empty set"

Comment: @Polymerase: Can you clarify what your doubt is? It seems pretty obvious from the definition of "proper subset" that a set cannot be a proper subset of itself, and it seems pretty obvious from the definition of "subset" that any set is a subset of itself. This is very similar to the `<` and `≤` algebraic relations on natural numbers: for all `a` the relation `a < a` is false, including `0`, and for all `a` the relation `a ≤ a` is true, including `0`. There is no contradiction there. Also, for all `a` the relation `0 ≤ a`, and for all `a` except `0`, the relation `0 < a` is true.

Comment: @JörgWMittag all clear now thanks. Reading [Proper subset definition](http://mathinsight.org/definition/proper_subset) has clarified.